# How to create ajax based top menu in magento?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have used this Ajax function to trigger event when the menu click, just need to know about which class will be used to load categories.

```
jQuery(".btn-mobile #sidebar-button").on("click",function(){
    if(jQuery('#sidebar-button').hasClass('active')){
                var categoryListingUrl = "categoryListing/index/index";
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    showLoader: true,
                    url: categoryListingUrl,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (request, error) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

======

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @see \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
 */
?>

<?php
$columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0;
$_menu        = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit);
$_config      = $this->helper('Sm\Destino\Helper\Data');
?>

<!--COLLAPSE-->
<?php if ($_config->getHeader('responsive_menu') == 'collapse') { ?>
    <div class="nav-mobile-container collapse-type">
        <div class="btn-mobile">
            <a id="collapse-button" class="button-mobile collapse-nav" title="<?php echo __('Categories') ?>"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><span class="hidden"><?php echo __('Categories') ?></span></a>
        </div>
        <nav class="navigation-mobile">
            <ul>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $_menu; 
                ?>
                
                <?php
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('megamenu2/other_menu/display_other_menu');
                    $titleNav = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('megamenu2/other_menu/other_menu_title');
                    $hrefNav = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('megamenu2/other_menu/other_menu_link');
                    if($conf){
                ?>
                <li class="level0 level-top">
                    <a class="level-top" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl($hrefNav) ?>">
                        <span><?php echo $titleNav; ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                'jquery'
            ], function ($) {
                $('#collapse-button').click(function () {
                    $('.navigation-mobile').slideToggle(200);
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                });

                $('.navigation-mobile > ul li').has('ul').append('<span class="touch-button"><span>open</span></span>');

                $('.touch-button').click(function () {
                    $(this).prev().slideToggle(200);
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('parent-active');
                });

            });
        </script>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<!--SIDEBAR-->
<?php if ($_config->getHeader('responsive_menu') == 'sidebar') { ?>
    <div class="nav-mobile-container sidebar-type">
        <div class="btn-mobile">
            <a id="sidebar-button" class="button-mobile sidebar-nav" title="<?php echo __('Categories') ?>"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><span class="hidden-xs menu-desk-title"><?php echo __('Product Category') ?></span></a>
        </div>
        <nav class="navigation-mobile">
            <div class="hidden-xs categories-panel-title"><?php echo __('All Categories') ?></div>
            <ul>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $_menu; 
                ?>
                
                <?php
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('megamenu2/other_menu/display_other_menu');
                    $titleNav = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('megamenu2/other_menu/other_menu_title');
                    $hrefNav = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('megamenu2/other_menu/other_menu_link');
                    if($conf){
                ?>
                <li class="level0 level-top">
                    <a class="level-top" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl($hrefNav) ?>">
                        <span><?php echo $titleNav; ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                'jquery'
            ], function ($) {
                $('#sidebar-button').click(function () {
                    $('body').toggleClass('navbar-active');
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                });

                $('.navigation-mobile > ul li').has('ul').append('<span class="touch-button"><span>open</span></span>');

                $('.touch-button').click(function () {
                    $(this).prev().slideToggle(200);
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('parent-active');
                });

            });
        </script>
        
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: any solution did u get ?

Comment: No I have used an alternate solution

Comment: Ya even i used jquery as a alternative solution

Comment: What is the alternate solution? could u pls provide the details here